Which Lie groups are covers of matrix groups?
I would like to ask a variation on a question (not yet answered) I previously asked on math.SE, namely:
Which Lie groups are covers of matrix Lie groups? That is, which Lie groups $G$ admit discrete normal subgroups $N$ for which $G/N$ is isomorphic to a matrix Lie group? In particular, is this true for all connected Lie groups $G$?
I ask this because, it seems to me (not an expert in Lie theory), the standard examples of Lie groups which are not isomorphic to matrix groups are things like the universal cover of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, which trivially covers a matrix group.
I also know of positive results in special cases (in part as a result of the discussion in the aforementioned math.SE question):

Compact Lie groups are matrix groups, a consequence of the Peter-Weyl Theorem.
Semisimple Lie groups are covers of their adjoint representations, which are matrix groups.
Simply connected Lie groups are covers of matrix groups, a consequence the correspondence between such groups and their Lie algebras, and Ado's Theorem (or Lie's Third Theorem).

Any references or related results are appreciated.

Just to save people a click: the Math.SE question was asked nearly a year ago!

Isn't this equivalent to the statement that $G$ have a finite dimensional almost faithful projective representation, and for this you can just choose any finite dimensional faithful representation of the Lie algebra of $G$?

@PaulLevy can you elaborate? What do you mean by "projective" representation? (Again, this is not really my area.)

A projective representation is a linear representation of $G$ on some projective space - so it's not in general a well-defined linear representation, but elements of $G$ have a well-defined action modulo scalar multiplication. My comment was stupid because a projective representation of $G$ would imply that some cover of $G$ is linear, which isn't what you want. But I think the general idea will work (see my next comment...).

I'm not that familiar with Lie groups, but I think the following will work: let $\hat{G}$ be the universal cover of $G$. Then any faithful representation of the Lie algebra of $G$ lifts to a representation of $\hat{G}$. We just choose a representation which is acted on trivially by the kernel of $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$. (Existence of such a representation is the point I'm least certain about - I'm not an expert.) This representation then gives a representation of $G$. Since it's faithful on the Lie algebra, then the kernel must be discrete.

Getting back to this, I think I came to another approach using projective representations, but there is a similar issue I don't understand: When does a linear representation of $\hat{G}$ induce a projective representation of $G$? Is this always true, over both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

The standard counterexample is as follows. Let $\tilde G$ be the Heisenberg group of $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal, and let $G$ be the quotient of $\tilde G$ by the subgroup generated by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. The $\tilde G$ is the universal cover of $G$. But no quotient of $G$ by a normal discrete subgroup has a finite dimensional faithful representation. To see this, look at the subgroup $\tilde Z$ of $\tilde G$ consisting of matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&a\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $Z$ be its image in $G$. Then $Z$ is a circle group, so every finite dimensional representation of $Z$ is diagonalisable, so it is a direct sum of one dimensional representations, and is determined by the traces of elements. Every element of the Lie algebra of $Z$ is a commutator of elements of the Lie algebra of $G$, and so its trace on any finite dimensional representation is equal to zero. A representation of $Z$ such that trace on every element of the Lie algebra is zero has to send every element of $Z$ to the identity. The upshot is that every finite dimensional representation of $G$ has $Z$ in the kernel, so the kernel is not discrete.

This example features in Section 4.8 of B. C. Hall's book, "Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations".

Thank you! This would also show that the remark, "All Lie groups with a given Lie algebra are covers of one another", made in the "Discussion and background" of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64195/when-is-a-finite-dimensional-real-or-complex-lie-group-not-a-matrix-group, is not correct when considering only covers with discrete kernel. That was the thing that started me down this rabbit hole.
